# Selenium deselects a password box when using send_keys instead of typing

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm a beginner with Selenium and pretty untested with Python, but I wanted to automate my Google sign in.
I can enter my email, and the program will wait a bit to make sure the page loads. As far as I can tell, it selects the correct box, but when it reaches send_keys the box disconnects.
Here's the code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')
driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin')
time.sleep(1) # Let the user actually see something!
sign_in = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
sign_in.send_keys('email')
time.sleep(1)
log_in = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext')
log_in.click()
time.sleep(5)
pass_key = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
pass_key.send_keys('password')
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: first check if you have two factor authentication present on your account .

Comment: I currently have it off.

Comment: google will detect you as a bot.  Better to use an existing profile or use google's API.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out after a bit, but I still think it'll be good to know why this is happening. Is it because of bot detection?